# Extract substrings from logical expressions

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string that looks like this:

```
myStr = '(Txt_l1 (Txt_l2)) or (Txt2_l1 (Txt2_l2))'
```

What I would like to obtain in the end would be:

```
myStr_l1 = '(Txt_l1) or (Txt2_l1)'
```

and

```
myStr_l2 = '(Txt_l2) or (Txt2_l2)'
```

Some properties:

- all "Txt_"-elements of the string start with an uppercase letter
- the string can contain much more elements (so there could also be `Txt3`, `Txt4`,...)
- the suffixes '_l1' and '_l2' look different in reality; they cannot be used for matching (I chose them for demonstration purposes)

I found a way to get the first part done by using:

```
myStr_l1 = re.sub('\(\w+\)','',myStr)
```

which gives me

```
'(Txt_l1 ) or (Txt2_l1 )'
```

However, I don't know how to obtain `myStr_l2`. My idea was to remove everything between two open parentheses. But when I do something like this:

```
re.sub('\(w+\(', '', myStr)
```

the entire string is returned.

```
re.sub('\(.*\(', '', myStr)
```

removes - of course - far too much and gives me

```
'Txt2_l2))'
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get `myStr_l2`?

When there is an "and" instead of an "or", the strings look slightly different:

```
myStr2 = '(Txt_l1 (Txt_l2) and Txt2_l1 (Txt2_l2))'
```

Then I can still use the command from above:

```
re.sub('\(\w+\)','',myStr2)
```

which gives:

```
'(Txt_l1  and Txt2_l1 )'
```

but I again fail to get `myStr2_l2`. How would I do this for these kind of strings?

And how would one then do this for mixed expressions with "and" and "or" e.g. like this:

```
myStr3 = '(Txt_l1 (Txt_l2) and Txt2_l1 (Txt2_l2)) or  (Txt3_l1 (Txt3_l2) and Txt4_l1 (Txt2_l2))' 

re.sub('\(\w+\)','',myStr3)
```

gives me

```
'(Txt_l1  and Txt2_l1 ) or  (Txt3_l1  and Txt4_l1 )'
```

but again: How would I obtain `myStr3_l2`?

Comment: Are `_l1` and `_l2` tags going to be the same every time they appear? You said those are different in reality but will the actual tag be the same each time it shows up or can Txt`_l1` be different from Txt2`_l1`?

Comment: No, there are always different suffixes. I used these only to clarify the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Regexp is not powerful enough for nested expressions (in your case: nested elements in parentheses). You will have to write a parser. Look at https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Could you give an idea how to apply the parser in the above case?

Comment: You need to parse the expression and build an AST (abstract syntax tree) which gives you a model of the elements that appear in the input.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want but I wrote this to strip everything between the parenthesis.

```
import re

mystr = '(Txt_l1 (Txt_l2)) or (Txt2_l1 (Txt2_l2))'
sets = mystr.split(' or ')
noParens = []
for line in sets:
    mat = re.match(r'\((.* )\((.*\)\))', line, re.M)
    if mat:
        noParens.append(mat.group(1))
        noParens.append(mat.group(2).replace(')',''))
print(noParens)
```

This takes all the parenthesis away and puts your elements in a list. Here's an alternate way of doing it without using Regular Expressions.

```
mystr = '(Txt_l1 (Txt_l2)) or (Txt2_l1 (Txt2_l2))'
noParens = []

mystr = mystr.replace(' or ', ' ')
mystr = mystr.replace(')','')
mystr = mystr.replace('(','')
noParens = mystr.split()

print(noParens)
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but that does not give the desired output. I don't want a list but strings (see in my question myStr_l1 and myStr_l2). I edit the question soon since it seems not clear what exactly I want to obtain.

Comment: I know you didn't want them in a list but I wasn't entirely sure what you were asking so I put them in a list for printing